# datatable boolean parse Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

May I know what the problem is in my if statement:

```
if(bool.Parse(Datatable.Rows[rowindex]["Ready?"].ToString()) == false){}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

There is no syntax error, but runtime error.

Comment: You need to find out what string is returned by `Datatable.Rows[rowindex]["Ready?"].ToString()` when the exception is thrown. If you know that, then you should already know the solution too.

Comment: Datatable.Columns.Add("Ready?", typeof(bool));
This is my column. Its a checked box. Seems to have an error when i run the codes

Comment: @andrioduser just do what bl4y said

Answer (score 1):

If type of column in database is bit, try

```
if ((bool)Datatable.Rows[rowindex]["Ready?"]){...} // column is not null
if (((bool?)Datatable.Rows[rowindex]["Ready?"]) != true){...} // column can contain null value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument of bool.Parse must equal Boolean.TrueString  or Boolean.FalseString. Otherwise a FormatException will be thrown.

Comment: With the ammendments that any whitespace can be before or after the `TrueString` or the `FalseString` and the comparison is case-insensitive.

Comment: Datatable.Columns.Add("Ready?", typeof(bool));

This is the column i had added to my datatable.
When the checkbox is unchecked, the return string seems to be null, not false.
I think thats the error.

Comment: @andrioduser It also can be `DBNull`, not the `null`, you can check that with `Convert.IsDBNull` method